# I need help figuring out this puzzling "Build Failed" error I keep getting

Tags: xml, build, error-handling

I cannot even find the string "SunAppServer" inside a source XML file or java file on my machine. I highlighted the trouble-spot.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\petstore~svn\trunk\ws\apps\petstore\build.xml:93: The following error occurre
d while executing this line:
C:\petstore~svn\trunk\ws\apps\petstore\setup\setup.xml:66: The following error o
ccurred while executing this line:
C:\petstore~svn\trunk\ws\bp-project\app-server-ant.xml:163: Execute failed: java
.io.IOException: Cannot run program "c:SunAppServer\bin\asadmin.bat": CreateProc
ess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Exec
ute.java:862)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:631)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(Single
CheckExecutor.java:38)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)

        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(Single
CheckExecutor.java:38)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExe
cutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find th
e file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
        ... 48 more

Total time: 0 seconds

C:\petstore~svn\trunk\ws\apps\petstore>
```

This is what makes no sense to me:
**Cannot run program "c:SunAppServer\bin\asadmin.bat"**

The only place I see the name SunAppServer is as the name of folders that were autom. made(by asadmin command of Glassfish) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C:\petstore~svn\trunk\ws\bp-project\app-server-ant.xml:163: Execute
>   failed: java .io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "c:SunAppServer\bin\asadmin.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system
>   cannot find the file specified

The solution is - maybe - to add a backslash in your path. "c:\S..." (in app-server-ant.xml line 163)

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find where to type it in; i.e, the word "SunAppServer" isn't located in the XML file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it working, and now I have a new issue, which I posted here, if you have time I'd greatly appreciate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355416/i-need-to-figure-out-why-ant-is-making-up-line-numbers-and-giving-me-weird-messag