# I need help figuring out why Ant is giving me this error messages(setting up Java Pet Store)?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ant, build, compiler-errors

I have no idea where ContainerBaCommand  is coming from, but here's my error:

I first had to add javax.jar (which has the servlet ) class into the C:\JEE6SDKglassfish3\glassfish\lib\endorsed directory, and it gave me a new error, here:

```
Buildfile: C:\petstore~svn\trunk\ws\apps\petstore\build.xml

check:

tools:

-pre-deploy:

deploy:
     [exec] Deprecated syntax, instead use:
     [exec] asadmin --user admin --passwordfile c:/JEE6SDKglassfish3/glassfish/samples/bp-project/passwordfile --host localhost --port 4848 deploy [options] ...

     [exec] remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBaCommand deploy failed.
     [exec] se.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener. Please see server.log for more details.

BUILD FAILED
C:\petstore~svn\trunk\ws\bp-project\app-server-ant.xml:382: exec returned: 1

Total time: 47 seconds
```

All the files in the setup folder: http://tinyurl.com/3gbb6o4

Edit: Thanks so much Mark!

Comment: I promise it's setup.xml. i can post both files too, below.

Comment: Could you post where db.classpath is defined? (probably in bp-project.xml) and also post javadb.properties for good measure.  I suspect there's a problem with the path because there is a newline in `c:\JEE6SDKglassfish3\
glassfish\javadb\lib`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the "**ContainerBaCommand**" is actually **ContainerBase.addChild** ([these guys had a similar problem](http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-675)).  I think sometimes Java standard output and standard errors get all mixed up on the console.

I assume you are using something like this [app-server-ant.xml](http://java.net/projects/petstore/sources/svn/content/trunk/ws/bp-project/app-server-ant.xml?rev=699). Your Ant error seems to be suggesting that the syntax that "**asadmin**" now uses to deploy your application has changed.  I therefore think you need to re-write your deploy task from what it is currently:

```
<exec executable="${asadmin}" failonerror="${failonerror}">
  <arg line=" deploy "/>
  <arg line=" --user ${javaee.server.username}" />
  <arg line=" --passwordfile ${javaee.server.passwordfile}" />
  <arg line=" --host ${javaee.adminserver.name}" />
  <arg line=" --port ${javaee.adminserver.port}" />
  <arg line=" --name ${module.name}"/>
  <arg line=" --force=true "/>
  <arg line=" --upload=true "/>
  <arg line=" --precompilejsp "/>
  <arg line=" --dbvendorname ${db.vendorname}"/>
  <arg line="${app.module}" />
</exec>
```

to:

```
<exec executable="${asadmin}" failonerror="${failonerror}">
  <arg line=" --user ${javaee.server.username}" />
  <arg line=" --passwordfile ${javaee.server.passwordfile}" />
  <arg line=" --host ${javaee.adminserver.name}" />
  <arg line=" --port ${javaee.adminserver.port}" />
  <arg line=" deploy "/>
  <arg line=" --force=true "/>
  <arg line=" --precompilejsp "/>
  <arg line=" --name ${module.name}"/>
  <arg line=" --upload=true "/>
  <arg line=" --dbvendorname ${db.vendorname}"/>
  <arg line="${app.module}" />
</exec>
```

I'm surprised that you needed to copy javax.jar (which has the servlet class) into lib endorsed.  The Servlet (and ServletContextListener for that matter) are very important classes for an application server. I would expect them to exist in the Glassfish class path already (in Glassfish 3.1 they are in *~glassfish/modules/javax.servlet.jar*).  I suspect copying your javax.jar into "**lib/endorsed**" is causing more problems than it would solve.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You so much Mark, I am indebted to you. This fixed it! I've also learned a valuable lesson about how important it is to pay close attention and think about the errors, and about how Ant works. Thanks again!